# How to disable Split Screen view

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6, multi-window

Hello I have a Galaxy S6 and I was wondering if there was any way to disable the split screen/multi-window option which appears above an app when you press the recents button. Are there any ways I can achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there apps which achieve this? If not, I thought of disabling the recent button somehow if this is possible. The reason I am trying to disable the split screen/multi-window view is so I can use an app called AppLock, but I can bypass it by using split screen/multi-window view. Any help is much appreciated.